# GObject to hold a pointer

Tags: gtk, glib, gtk4

In a GTK4 program I am using:

```
DataObject *dataObject = data_object_new();
....
gtk_builder_set_current_object (builder, dataObject );
```

to set the default "user_data" for GTK4 widget callbacks.
I would like this to be a simple pointer (as I had it in GTK3) but GTK4 requires the second argument of `gtk_builder_set_current_object` to be a pointer to a GObject (and fails at run time if its just a cast pointer). I can create a special GObject (as shown above) but is there an easier way that I'm missing?
Are there any existing standard GObject derived types that simply hold a pointer?
I tried to create an object of type `G_TYPE_POINTER` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question ...

```
GObject *dataObject = g_object_new( G_TYPE_OBJECT, NULL );
g_object_set_data( dataObject, "data", (gpointer)&data );

gtk_builder_set_current_object (builder, dataObject );
```